# Login Required decorator not redirecting to login url | Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

@login_required decorator not redirecting me to the login page

When I click the add to cart button it doesn't redirect me to the login page. It just doesn't do anything. I tried the login required decorator in another function. Like the home view action. And when I try to access the home page it directly redirects me to the login page. But in the `combo_add_to_cart` it doesn't seems to work. But I have found something in the terminal. I have seen that when I click the add to cart button it first sends a `post` request of `"POST /carts/cart/combo/add-to-cart/ "` then it sends a `get` request `"GET /accounts/login/?next=/carts/cart/combo/add-to-cart/"`

`accounts views.py`

```
class Login(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        request = self.request
        next_ = request.GET.get('next')
        next_post = request.POST.get('next')
        redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
                return redirect(redirect_path)
            else:
                return redirect("/")
        return super(Login, self).form_invalid(form)
```

`cart views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def combo_add_to_cart(request):    
    combo_id = request.POST.get('combo_id')
    if combo_id is not None:
        try:
            combo_obj = Combo.objects.get(id=combo_id)
        except Combo.DoesNotExist:
            return("carts:cart")

        combo = combo_obj

        cart_item, created = ComboCartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            combo=combo,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )

        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)

        if cart_obj.combo_item.filter(combo__id=combo.id).exists():
            cart_item.quantity += 1
            cart_item.save()
            print("Cart Item Updated")
            added = False
            updated = True
            # return redirect("carts:cart")
        else:
            cart_obj.combo_item.add(cart_item)
            print("Combo Added")
            added = True
            updated = False
            # return redirect("carts:cart")

        # print(combo_id)
        cartCount = cart_obj.get_cartItems()
        print(cartCount)
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("Ajax Request")
            json_data = {
            "added": added,
            # "not_added": not added,
            "updated": updated,
            # "not_updated": not updated
            "ItemCount": cartCount
            }   
            return JsonResponse(json_data, status=200)
            # return JsonResponse("message: Error", status_code=400)

    return redirect("carts:cart")
```

```
class ComboList(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ComboList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        combo = Combo.objects.all()
        return combo
```

`combo-update.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'carts:combo_add_to_cart' %}" data-endpoint="{% url 'carts:combo_add_to_cart' %}" class="form add-ajax">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="combo_id" value="{{ combo.id }}">
    <span class="submit-span">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

`list.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Combos</h1>
        <hr>
        {% for obj in object_list %}
            <b style="font-size: 1.5em;">{{ obj.title }} | Regular Rs.{{ obj.combo_regular_price }} | Sale Rs.{{ obj.combo_sale_price }}</b>

            {% include "products/snippets/combo-update.html" with combo=obj %}

            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.js`

```
var comboForm = $(".add-ajax")

  comboForm.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var thisForm = $(this)
    var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("data-endpoint");
    var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
    var formData = thisForm.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: actionEndpoint,
      method: httpMethod,
      data: formData,
      success: function(data){
        var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")

        if(data.added){
          submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add More?</button>')
          swal({
          title: "",
          text: "Added to cart!",
          icon: "success",
          button: "Okay",
        })
        }else{
          if(data.updated){
            submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add More?</button>')
          }else{
            submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>')
          }
        }
        var cartCount = $(".cart-count")
        cartCount.text(data.ItemCount)
        console.log(data.ItemCount)
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('cart') != -1){
          refreshCart()
        }
      },
      error: function(errorData){
        swal({
          title: "Opps!",
          text: "An error occured!",
          icon: "error",
          button: "Okay",
        })

        console.log("No API")
        console.log("error", errorData)
      }
    })

  })
```

`Traceback`

```
[01/Jun/2020 19:05:26] "POST /carts/cart/combo/add-to-cart/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[01/Jun/2020 19:05:26] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/carts/cart/combo/add-to-cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4146
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the javascript that I wrote!

Firs in my `cart views.py` file I added

```
def combo_add_to_cart(request):    
    combo_id = request.POST.get('combo_id')
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("Ajax Request")
            json_data = {
            "noUser": True,
            }   
            return JsonResponse(json_data, status=200)
    else:        
        if combo_id is not None:
            try:
                combo_obj = Combo.objects.get(id=combo_id)
```

In the ajax call of `base.js` I added a condition

```
        if(data.noUser){
          swal({
            title: "Opps! You are not logged in",
            text: "Redirecting......",
            button: false,
          })
          setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href='/accounts/login/'
          }, 1000)
        }else{
          if(data.added){
            submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add More?</button>')
            swal({
            title: "",
            text: "Added to cart!",
            icon: "success",
            button: "Okay",
          })
          }else{
            if(data.updated){
              submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add More?</button>')
            }else{
              submitSpan.html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>')
            }
          }
        }
```

So now it works even without the login_required decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even need the js part. The answer was simple

I just replaced `@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')`  with `@login_required(login_url="accounts:login")`.

I don't know actually why it didn't work as the url was mapped properly. Now I just changed it to use the `namespace` and `url` name, and it works.